# DataBase on Mac OS

Tags: database, macos

It is my first time I develop on Mac OS.

Can anyone suggest a client side DB on Mac OS?

A Database that works the same on both Windows and MAC would be great...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a MAC developer, but will your requirement fit [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)? Here's a [tutorial](http://www.razorsql.com/articles/sqlite_mac.html) on Getting Started.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads) or [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx).

Comment: @Jinith, I see, I think I misunderstood the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have came across a DB SQLite which seems to be a gud solution, am working on it :- 
http://www.javaworkspace.com/connectdatabase/connectSQLite.do

Comment: you should rather accept an answer that best resolved your question instead of posting a comment in the answer block.

Comment: @The Elite, its not a comment but an answer to my Question that may help others to so i posted it...

Answer (score 0):

With the Mac, you are entering a different universe.  It is not possible to get something tha works the same in two different Universes.  If you go with that requirement, then you are basically limited to what is available in the Windoze/Linux market (which is light years behind the Mac).

FileMaker is the best by far. Forget about writing code, in SQL or anything else.  Everything, all functions, via a very mature GUI.  The application is also Full GUI.

PostgreSQL is an abomination.  Check SO yourself for problem posts.  It is the latest incarnation of Ingres, which was horrible.

MySQL is not a server architecture, really.